# Different log files using Logback

Tags: java, logback

I would like to log different log levels to different files , In addition to this I would like to have the default consoleAppender as well for each log level.

So the output should be different log level files :

1. Info level file
2. Warn level file
3. Error level file
4. Console should also remain enabled all the time.

```
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{35}) - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

    <!-- Logging settings for the info logs -->
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
      <level>INFO</level>
      <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
    </filter> 
    <file>logs\logFile.html</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>logs\logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.html</fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
          <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 50MB -->
        <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
      <!-- keep 60 days' worth of history -->
      <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}%thread%level%logger%line%msg</pattern>
      </layout>         
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <!-- Logging settings for the error logs -->
  <appender name="FILEERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
      <level>ERROR</level>
      <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
    </filter> 
    <file>logs\logFileError.html</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>logs\logFileError.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.html</fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
          <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 50MB -->
        <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
      <!-- keep 60 days' worth of history -->
      <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}%thread%level%logger%line%msg</pattern>
      </layout>         
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <!-- Logging settings for the warn logs -->
  <appender name="FILEWARN" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
      <level>WARN</level>
      <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
    </filter> 
    <file>logs\logFileWarn.html</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>logs\logFileWarn.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.html</fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
          <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 50MB -->
        <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
      <!-- keep 60 days' worth of history -->
      <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}%thread%level%logger%line%msg</pattern>
      </layout>         
    </encoder>
  </appender>   

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />     
  </root>

  <root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILEERROR" />     
  </root>

  <root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILEWARN" />     
  </root>

</configuration>
```

The problem here is it writes each type of level in all files.

Comment: You can only define root level once. You need to use different loggers and then reference the matching appenders. Possibly you have to adjust the additivity behavior as described here: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Comment: Any example for this would help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update the filter definitions to include: `<onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>`, for example:

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
  <level>INFO</level>
  <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
  <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch> 
</filter>
```

The default behaviour for `onMismatch` is `FilterReply.NEUTRAL` so by not including a `onMismatch` declaration you are effectively allowing all entries through the filter whether they match the given level or not.

You should also remove the multiple `<root>` declarations and replace them with this one:

```
<root level="info">
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  <appender-ref ref="FILEWARN" /> 
  <appender-ref ref="FILEERROR" />      
</root>
```

This declaration will cause all four of those appenders to be running and then the filter within each of the `FILE`, `FILEWARN` and `FILEERROR` appenders will ensure that they only handle log events of the correct level.

Comment: This is exactly what I did and it started working. :)

Comment: For me it is also working like this <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILEERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILEWARN" />      
  </root>

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done , and it is working.

> ```
> <configuration>
>
>   <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
>     <!-- encoders are assigned the type
>          ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
>     <encoder>
>       <charset>UTF-8</charset>
>       <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{35}) - %msg %n</pattern>
>     </encoder>
>   </appender>
>
>   <!-- Logging settings for the info logs -->
>   <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
>       <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
>       <level>INFO</level>
>       <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
>       <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
>     </filter> 
>     <file>logs\logFile.html</file>
>     <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
>       <!-- daily rollover -->
>       <fileNamePattern>logs\logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.html</fileNamePattern>
>       <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
>           class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
>           <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 50MB -->
>         <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
>       </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
>       <!-- keep 60 days' worth of history -->
>       <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
>     </rollingPolicy>
>     <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
>       <charset>UTF-8</charset>
>       <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
>         <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}%thread%level%logger%line%msg</pattern>
>       </layout>         
>     </encoder>
>   </appender>
>
>   <!-- Logging settings for the error logs -->
>   <appender name="FILEERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
>   <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
>       <level>ERROR</level>
>       <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
>       <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
>     </filter> 
>     <file>logs\logFileError.html</file>
>     <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
>       <!-- daily rollover -->
>       <fileNamePattern>logs\logFileError.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.html</fileNamePattern>
>       <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
>           class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
>           <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 50MB -->
>         <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
>       </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
>       <!-- keep 60 days' worth of history -->
>       <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
>     </rollingPolicy>
>     <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
>       <charset>UTF-8</charset>
>       <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
>         <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}%thread%level%logger%line%msg</pattern>
>       </layout>         
>     </encoder>
>   </appender>
>
>   <!-- Logging settings for the warn logs -->
>   <appender name="FILEWARN" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
>   <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
>       <level>WARN</level>
>       <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
>       <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
>     </filter> 
>     <file>logs\logFileWarn.html</file>
>     <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
>       <!-- daily rollover -->
>       <fileNamePattern>logs\logFileWarn.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.html</fileNamePattern>
>       <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
>           class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
>           <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 50MB -->
>         <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
>       </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
>       <!-- keep 60 days' worth of history -->
>       <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
>     </rollingPolicy>
>     <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
>       <charset>UTF-8</charset>
>       <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
>         <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}%thread%level%logger%line%msg</pattern>
>       </layout>         
>     </encoder>
>   </appender>  
>
>    <root level="debug">
>     <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
>     <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
>     <appender-ref ref="FILEERROR" />
>     <appender-ref ref="FILEWARN" />      
>   </root> 
>
> <!--   <root level="info">
>     <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
>     <appender-ref ref="FILE" />     
>   </root>
>
>   <root level="error">
>     <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
>     <appender-ref ref="FILEERROR" />     
>   </root>
>
>   <root level="warn">
>     <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
>     <appender-ref ref="FILEWARN" />     
>   </root> -->
>
> </configuration>
> ```